# Python os.path.join() not joining properly when using cron job

Tags: python, logging, cron, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I have a python script at /home/pi/update_rrd_data.py that's supposed to store logs in the folder /home/pi/logs_rrd.

This is how I've implemented it:

```
current_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.stack()[0][1]))
log_folder = os.path.join(current_folder, 'logs_rrd')
if not os.path.exists(log_folder): os.makedirs(log_folder)

file_name = __file__[:-3]  + '_' + datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y%m%d%H%M') + '.log'
log_file = os.path.join(log_folder, file_name)

logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(filename)s->%(funcName)s:%(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y_%I:%M:%S_%p')
logging.info('\nCurrent Folder: {}\nLog Folder: {}\nLog File: {}'.format(current_folder, log_folder, log_file))
```

When I run the script manually, it works fine and this is what I get in the log file at /home/pi/logs_rrd/update_rrd_data_201709271426.log:
Current Folder: /home/pi
Log Folder:     /home/pi/logs_rrd
Log File:       /home/pi/logs_rrd/update_rrd_data_201709271426.log

However, when I run it as a cron job, the log files are created in the same folder as the script instead of the logs_rrd folder. This is what I get in the log file at /home/pi/update_rrd_data_201709271445.log:
Current Folder: /home/pi
Log Folder:     /home/pi/logs_rrd
Log File:       /home/pi/update_rrd_data_201709271445.log

I can't figure out why the log folder value is ok but then the log file removes the logs_rrd part of log folder.

This is how I run the cron:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/pi/update_rrd_data.py
```

All the folders and files are owned by root so there shouldn't be any write permission issues.

Comment: Did you try to use `__file__` instead `inspect.stack()[0][1]`?

Comment: @AndMar Yes I did but then the Current Folder becomes /root. Also, the values of current folder and log folder are correct either way. It's when I try to combine the file name to the log folder that it acts weird and removes the "logs_rrd" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the case where it doesn't work, `__file__` is probably an absolute path, so

```
log_file = os.path.join(log_folder, file_name)
```

has no effect, (it retuns `file_name`) and the original script directory is kept.

Instead of `__file__[:-3]`, just do:

```
os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(__file__)[0])
```

to get rid of the extension (which may not be `.py` in some cases BTW) *and* of the script file path in all cases, so the next `os.path.join` command works properly.

Alternate solution using `pathlib` and a `Path` object (requires Python 3):

```
pathlib.Path(__file__).with_suffix('').name
```

that removes the directory & the file extension amounting to the same result.

Comment: I've become partial to `pathlib.Path`, so `p = pathlib.Path(__file__)` then simply `p.with_suffix('').name` *So* much more readable than `os.path.blahblahblah(os.path.bloop(path)[0])`

Comment: I always used `os.path`, but okay.

Comment: Same, it wasn't until recently that I started, but it has lots of wonderful features. Instead of `os.join`, *it overloads the `/` operator*  (as well as making it available as a method)!!! Well worth checking out: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: had a quick look and it's really good. thanks for pointing this out. The `/` operator is a nice addition.

Comment: pathlib sounds cool but I should have mentioned I'm using python 2.7 so I can't use that..

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks a lot for the answer! I should probably have printed the file_name variable in the log and that'd have made things much clearer. I have never used os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(__file__)[0]) and you're right sometimes the extension isn't .py (it's .py*) and I've had to add logic in my script to detect that. I'll update all my other scripts too now :)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga now I know why I'm not using `pathlib`: I'm stuck with python 2.7 compatibility at work :(